# ssh-add permanently using ansible

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I'm trying to add a SSH key to SSH agent using ssh-add in ansible tasks.

My ansible task for it looks like this:

```
- name: add id_rsa in ssh-agent
  shell: eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey
```

and it returns the following results:

```
TASK: [add id_rsa in ssh-agent] *********************************************** 
changed: [testcom.mydomain.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey", "delta": "0:00:00.086725", "end": "2015-08-26 13:35:38.527742", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-08-26 13:35:38.441017", "stderr": "Could not create keychain item\nIdentity added: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey (/var/root/.ssh/id_rsa_mykey)", "stdout": "Agent pid 8559", "warnings": []}
```

I don't know why it couldn't add the key to the keychain but it seems like the key has been added. However when I check with ssh-add -l, it says that the agent has no identities. I couldn't find out where the problem lies.

The key can be added manually in terminal using the same command.

Comment: Do you intend to add this key for user root?

Comment: @udondan yes I intend to add it for root. Would that cause problems?

Comment: I was just wondering, since it wasn't mentioned in the question but the generated output showed the task was run as root. Just thought that might have been accidental and you were looking at the wrong user.

Comment: @udondan oh, I see, sorry I should've mentioned it in the question. Yes, I'm running the playbook as root user and checked the agent for root user if the key has been added. According to the answer from Alister Bulman, it looks like ssh-add doesn't take effect directly in the ansible task.

Comment: even if this would work, you wouldn't know have the environment variables ssh-agent sets after this task ran. You could write yourself a wrapper script though, which would redirect ssh-agent's output to a file which you then can `source` later into your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssh-agent` effect is limited to a single task which invokes it because the connection info to `ssh-agent` is kept in the environment variables.  You might want to see what you eval in the task.

```
$ ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-uKzY20owbmmf/agent.8285; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=8286; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 8286;
```

You cannot use this `ssh-agent` in later tasks or interactive sessions without settings shown above.

In any cases I never recommend to run `ssh-agent` in this way (`eval $(ssh-agent)`).  It's hard to properly finish daemonized `ssh-agent` on quit, very easy to make ownerless `ssh-agent` processes in the system.  It would be much better to utilize SSH agent forwarding instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to be adding the key to the agent from the bash/zsh/etc startup scripts. You can add those lines to the files via Ansible, but it won't do much good otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is still possible to run `ssh-add` in an Ansible task so that later tasks can use the keys that I add. But it is necessary to remove  `` eval `ssa-agent` `` from the playbook and run it separately before the playbook starts. This is so that the agent's environment variables can be seen by the Ansible tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
- name: Load keys to SSH-Agent      
      shell: "ssh -o ForwardAgent=no {{inventory_hostname}} 'eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa && ssh-add -l'"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I'm running the shell command from my laptop vs remotely , and then ssh w/o forwarding my personal agent/keys to the remote server, starting clean.

You can remove the last part of `ssh-add -l` this was just to run the playbook with `-vvv` and see the output of the remote command. can be removed.